# Set up TigerVNC on Ubuntu 20.02 with systemd

Tags: systemd, vnc, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to setup TigerVNC - or indeed any VNC server - on Ubuntu 20.04, and I am beginning to get frustrated, because none of the instructions I can find actually work, although I have got it to work on CentOS. This is what I want to achieve, and as I understand it, TigerVNC should be able to handle it:

- Offer VNC service to several users
- The user should be asked for username and password
- It must work with systemd

I have been through more helpful web-pages than I care to list, but the latest, slightly successful one was [TigerVNC (on Arch Linux)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TigerVNC), the section `Running Xvnc with XDMCP for on demand sessions`.

The system is simple: Ubuntu 20.04 with the default desktop, which seems to be GNOME based - not what I would have chosen, but then this isn't for my use. `/var/log/syslog` lists a large number of outputs from when I try to connect, but I think the following contains the relevant error:

```
...
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop[555768]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop[555768]: Cannot open display:
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop[555770]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop[555770]: Cannot open display:
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session[555468]: gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session[555468]: gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-session[555468]: gnome-session-binary[555468]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron gnome-shell[555777]: Failed to create backend: Unable to open display '127.0.0.1:1'
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[555774]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul 22 14:22:34 megatron org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[555774]: Cannot open display:
...
```

On the client side (OSX) I just see a dialog telling me it can't connect. How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my answer is a little late, but I hope it will be helpful nevertheless.
I had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and I lost two days for finding a solution.

Try this:

1. Install TigerVNC, i.e. tigervnc-standalone-server on the server.
2. Follow the guide for setting up the server, e.g. 
   https://docs.01.org/clearlinux/latest/guides/network/vnc.html 
   See "Method 3: Multi-user logins with authentication through GDM" 
   Short details: 
   a) Create a systemd socket file */etc/systemd/system/xvnc.socket* with the following content:

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=XVNC Server on port 5900

    [Socket]
    ListenStream=5900
    Accept=yes

    [Install]
    WantedBy=sockets.target
   ```

   b) Create a systemd service file */etc/systemd/system/xvnc@.service* with the following content:

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=Daemon for each XVNC connection

    [Service]
    ExecStart=-/usr/bin/Xvnc -inetd -query localhost -geometry 1920x1200 -once -SecurityTypes=None
    User=nobody
    StandardInput=socket
   ```

   c) In file */etc/gdm3/custom.conf* set:

   ```
    [xdmcp]
    Enable=true
    Port=177
   ```

   d) Start the VNC socket script and set it to start automatically on boot.

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl enable xvnc.socket
   sudo systemctl start xvnc.socket
   ```

   e) Check. If you do

   ```
   systemctl | grep vnc
   ```

   you should see at least:

   ```
   xvnc.socket               loaded active listening XVNC Server on port 5900
   ```
3. In the file */etc/gdm3/custom.conf* uncomment the line:

   ```
   WaylandEnable=false
   ```

   It solves the problem with black screen right after connection.
4. ***Edit:***
   In the file */etc/gdm3/custom.conf* in section [xdmcp] add:

   ```
   DisplaysPerHost=5
   ```

   Where *5* is example of your max. number of allowed VNC connections.

   It solves the problem "read (104: Connection reset by peer)" for more connections.
5. In the file */etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults* find parameter $session and set:

   ```
   $session = ubuntu
   ```

   (for the possible session values look at folder */usr/share/xsessions*, use names without .desktop suffix)

   It solves the problem with black screen after login screen.
6. Try to connect from client to <server-ip>:5900.